# How do you add new custom attributetypes to existing objectclasses in LDAP

Tags: windows, ldap, apache-ds

How the heck do we add new attributes to existing object?

For example, I have a custom LDAP objectclass:

```
m-oid=1.1.1.1.1.1...
  m-must: uid
  m-may: role
  m-may: cn
  m-may: sn
```

Then I added some records of the above object into the server... and then I decided to add 2 new attributes to the existing objectclass...

```
m-oid=1.1.1.1.1.1...
  m-must: uid
  m-may: role
  m-may: cn
  m-may: sn
  m-may: newone
  m-may: newtwo
```

For some weird reason, it let me add `newone` but it won't let me add `newtwo`, yet both of them are just `octet string` with their own unique `m-oid`.

What is the proper way to add new attributes to existing object? and what happen to existing records?

I am using Apache Directory Studio. Don't have `ldapmodify` or stuff like that.